# c# get iframe kod with htmlagilitypack?

Tags: c#, iframe, html-agility-pack

I am using C# with HtmlAgilityPack and I want to get iframe kod froma a website's html.

This is the iframe area:

```
<div class="playercont">
   <div id="singlePlay" class="dp_player" data-o="" data-s="">
      <p><iframe src="video.com/sadas" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" width="640" height="360" allowfullscreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true"></iframe></p>
   </div>
</div>
```

I want to get that iframe with console or application,
the output I want is:

```
<iframe src="video.com/sadas" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" width="640" height="360" allowfullscreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true"></iframe>
```

Please give me some examples or the exact code for this.

****UPDATE : After some minutes, I got the code with a little mistake
here is the code:

```
var url = "my html url";

var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var html =  await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);
var htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDocument.LoadHtml(html);


HtmlNode divContainer = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='someclass']");


Console.WriteLine(divContainer.InnerHtml);
```

The above code gave me this:

```
<p><iframe src="video.com/sadas" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" width="640" height="360" allowfullscreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true"></iframe></p>
```

Finally, I want to exclude "p" tag from output, please help me with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to grab the iframe from the divContainer node and then use `OuterHtml` to get the html content:

```
HtmlNode divContainer = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='singlePlay']");

HtmlNode iframe = divContainer.SelectSingleNode("//iframe");

Console.WriteLine(iframe.OuterHtml);
```